# EOF: command not found in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: bash, jenkins

I'm trying to launch Datadog agent in Jenkins pipeline, but I'm getting below errors:

line 7: warning: here-document at line 2 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF'). EOF: Command not found Error.

```
    stage('Install Datadog agent'){
        when {
            environment(name: "DATADOG_REQ", value: "enable")
            }
        steps {
            script {
            echo "Installing Datadog Agent"
            
            sh '''#!/bin/bash 
                ssh -o ConnectTimeout=30 -t  ABC@1234 /bin/bash  << EOF || error_exit "creating based folder failed for $service_name"
                sudo chmod u+x ./${JOB_NAME}/enableDatadogAgent.sh
                sudo chown jenkins:jenkins ./${JOB_NAME}/enableDatadogAgent.sh
                echo ${DATADOG_REQ} ${JOB_NAME}
                ./${JOB_NAME}/enableDatadogAgent.sh ${DATADOG_REQ} 
                EOF'''
                }



            }
        }
```

Any help would be very helpful.

Comment: It's probably the indentation - see for example [Multiline bash command in Jenkins pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44842259/multiline-bash-command-in-jenkins-pipeline)

Answer (score 0):

stage('Install Datadog agent'){
when {
environment(name: "DATADOG_REQ", value: "enable")
}
steps {
script {
echo "Installing Datadog Agent"

```
        sh '''#!/bin/bash 
            ssh -o ConnectTimeout=30 -t  ABC@1234 /bin/bash  << EOF || error_exit "creating based folder failed for $service_name"
            sudo chmod u+x ./${JOB_NAME}/enableDatadogAgent.sh
            sudo chown jenkins:jenkins ./${JOB_NAME}/enableDatadogAgent.sh
            echo ${DATADOG_REQ} ${JOB_NAME}
            ./${JOB_NAME}/enableDatadogAgent.sh ${DATADOG_REQ} 
            << EOF'''
            }
```